# Changing the program to take standard input

Tags: python, linux

```
#!/usr/local/cs/bin/python3

import argparse
import random
import sys

def shuf_lines(lines, repeat, head_count, zero_terminated):
    delimiter = '\0' if zero_terminated else '\n'
    if repeat and not head_count:
        while True:
            print(random.choice(lines), end=delimiter)
    else:
        random.shuffle(lines)
        count = min(head_count, len(lines)) if head_count else len(lines)
        for i in range(count):
            print(lines[i], end=delimiter)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        prog='shuf',
        description='Write a random permutation of the input lines to standard output.',
        add_help=False
    )

    parser.add_argument('-e', '--echo', action='store_true',
                        help='treat each ARG as an input line')
    parser.add_argument('-i', '--input-range',
                        metavar='LO-HI', help='treat each number LO through HI as an input line')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--head-count', type=int,
                        help='output at most COUNT lines')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--repeat', action='store_true',
                        help='output lines can be repeated')
    parser.add_argument('-z', '--zero-terminated', action='store_true',
                        help='line delimiter is NUL, not newline')
    parser.add_argument('--help', action='help',
                        help='display this help and exit')
    parser.add_argument('files', metavar='SOURCE', nargs = '*',
                        help='input file name or - for standard input')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    input_lines = []
    if args.echo:
        input_lines = args.files
    elif args.files:
        for file in args.files:
            if file == '-' or file == None:
                input_lines.extend(sys.stdin.read().split())
            else:
                try:
                    with open(file, 'r') as f:
                        input_lines.extend(f.read().split())
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    sys.exit(f"shuf: {file}: No such file or directory")
    else:
        input_lines.extend(sys.stdin.read().split())

    if args.echo or args.files:
        shuf_lines(input_lines, args.repeat, args.head_count, args.zero_terminated)
    elif args.input_range:
        try:
            start, end = map(int, args.input_range.split('-'))
            input_lines = list(map(str, range(start, end + 1)))
            shuf_lines(input_lines, args.repeat, args.head_count, args.zero_terminated)
        except ValueError:
            sys.exit("shuf: invalid input range")
    
    else:
        sys.exit("shuf: missing operand")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to recreate the shuf command in python.

I'd like for my code to accept standard input if the operand is nothing. How would I change it do so.

Right now running it with no arguments lets me input, but I get an error, "invalid argument". I tried to also add the None argument for the files input but that didn't help either.

Running the program with no operand and inputting the following:

```
one
two
three
four
```

ctrl-d

I get: `shuf: missing operand`

Comment: _but I get an error, "invalid argument"_ Please edit the question to show the exact arguments you used, and the full error traceback message.

Comment: You've already handled the case where `args.files` is empty in the first `if` statement; there's no reason to exit with an error when it is *still* empty in the second `if` statement.

Comment: Maybe you want [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html)?

Comment: What's the "invalid argument" error? If you're not getting that error anymore, please [edit] to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly exiting with an error when `args.files` is empty, even though you've already populated `input_lines` from standard input.

Your first `if` statement should handle *all* possible ways to provide input, including when `args.range` is true. (Also, if `args.files` is empty, simply add a `-` to it and handle it the same as if `-` were passed expclitly.) (And note that `args.files` will never contain the value `None`.)

```
input_lines = []
if not args.files:
    args.files = ['-']

if args.echo:
    input_lines = args.files
elif args.files:
    for file in args.files:
        if file == '-':
            input_lines.extend(sys.stdin.read().split())
        else:
            try:
                with open(file, 'r') as f:
                    input_lines.extend(f.read().split())
            except FileNotFoundError:
                sys.exit(f"shuf: {file}: No such file or directory")
elif args.range:
    try:
        start, end = map(int, args.input_range.split('-'))
        input_lines = list(map(str, range(start, end + 1)))
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit("shuf: invalid input range")
else:
    sys.exit("No source of lines detected")
```

Once you've done that, you need only call `shut_lines` *unconditionally*:

```
shut_lines(input_lines, args.repeat, args.head_count, args.zero_terminated)
```

Comment: Thank you! After adding the if not args.files:
    args.files = ['-'] it seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fileinput` library for this purpose:

Instead of:

```py
    elif args.files:
        for file in args.files:
            if file == '-' or file == None:
                input_lines.extend(sys.stdin.read().split())
            else:
                try:
                    with open(file, 'r') as f:
                        input_lines.extend(f.read().split())
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    sys.exit(f"shuf: {file}: No such file or directory")
    else:
        input_lines.extend(sys.stdin.read().split())
```

do:

```py
import fileinput
...

    input_lines.extend(fileinput.input(args.files))
```

If `args.files` is `None` or an empty list, then input lines will be taken from the standard input. If `args.files` is a list of file names, then input lines will be taken from there.

Comment: I am limited as to what libraries I can use. The ones in the program are the only ones available for use.

Comment: `fileinput` is a module in the same library as `argparse`: the standard library.

Comment: If using `fileinput` is really out of the question, `argparse.FileType` understands the "`-` for standard input" convention as well.